# How could you demonstrate that array types are reference types?

Tags: java, arrays, types, reference

This is a past exam question and I'm not sure how you would answer that to get full credit.

> How could you demonstrate that array types are reference types?

Comment: I've inferred this to be about Java, but I could be wrong. Please tag appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6938f28.aspx

Create an array type outside of a method and populate it with values.

Send it into the method and change a value.

Read it outside of the method to see that the value did actually change.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class ArraysAreReferences {

  public static void changeIt(int[] arr) {
    arr[0] = 1000;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
    changeIt(arr);  

    // If arrays are passed by reference arr[0] should now be 1000...
    System.out.println(arr[0]);  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could pass an object of array type to a function which modifies it and observe that the original array has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is about Java (in line with all your previous questions), the canonical way is to quote the [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/arrays.html#10.1):

> **10.2 Array Variables**
>
> A variable of array type holds a reference to an object.

Empirically:

```
System.out.println(new int[0] instanceof Object);
```